# Live watch display problem in interactive menu

Tags: c++, multithreading, datetime, menu

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>

namespace jsw 
{
    namespace threading {
        class auto_event {
        public:
            auto_event(): _event(CreateEvent(0, false, false, 0)) {}

            BOOL wait(DWORD timeout = 1) const
            {
                return WaitForSingleObject(_event, timeout) == WAIT_OBJECT_0;
            }

            BOOL set() { return SetEvent(_event); }
        private:
            HANDLE _event;
        };

        class thread {
        public:
            static thread start(
                LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE fn, LPVOID args = 0,
                DWORD state = 0, DWORD timeout = 1000)
            {
                return thread(CreateThread(0, 0, fn, args, state, 0), timeout);
            }

            static void sleep(DWORD milliseconds) { Sleep(milliseconds); }
            static void exit(DWORD exitCode) { ExitThread(exitCode); }
        public:
            thread(HANDLE thread, DWORD timeout): _thread(thread), _timeout(timeout) {}
            ~thread() { CloseHandle(_thread); }

            DWORD exit_code() const
            {
                DWORD exitCode = NO_ERROR;

                GetExitCodeThread(_thread, &exitCode);

                return exitCode;
            }

            HANDLE handle() const { return _thread; }
            BOOL is_alive() const { return exit_code() == STILL_ACTIVE; }
            DWORD join() { return WaitForSingleObject(_thread, _timeout); }
            DWORD suspend() { return SuspendThread(_thread); }
            DWORD resume() { return ResumeThread(_thread); }
            BOOL abort(DWORD exitCode) { return TerminateThread(_thread, exitCode); }
        private:
            HANDLE _thread;
            DWORD _timeout;
        };
    }
}

using namespace std;

DWORD WINAPI get_password(LPVOID args)
{
    using namespace jsw::threading;

    string *s = (string*)((LPVOID*)args)[0];
    auto_event *e = (auto_event*)((LPVOID*)args)[1];

    *s=getch();
    e->set();

    return NO_ERROR;
}

void time()
{
    //...I'll get it
}

int main()
{
    using namespace jsw::threading;

    string password;
    auto_event e;
    LPVOID args[2] = {&password, &e};

    thread worker = thread::start(get_password, args);

    cout<<"time of game --> ";time();cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Press one to go home"<<endl;
    cout<<"Press two to drive your car"<<endl;
    cout<<"Press three to visit near city"<<endl;

    if (e.wait(1000))
    {
        if(password=="1")      cout<<"House"<<endl;
        else if(password=="2") cout<<"Car"<<endl;
        else if(password=="3") cout<<"City"<<endl;
        else                   cout<<"wrong option"<<endl;
    }
    else  system("cls"); main();




    return 0;
}
```

When the second on the clock changes and I select an option in the menu, I have to click the button several times because the first time the program does not load it. When starting the program, it loads correctly, but after a second, when the program uses else, I have to click the button several times.

(I need this procedure to change time with passing seconds in the program)

looking for a time limited cin I just found this code "namespace jsw" and "DWORD WINAPI". It works, because when the time is up, the program redisplays the menu with the changed time, but when retrieving a key there is a problem.